# Problems with namespace

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I have to retrieve the SID of a C# software in order to connect it with Facebook.
I saw that I have to print this:
`string sid=WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();`
But it's written that `WebAuthenticationBroker` doesn't exist in the context.
So I added `using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;` but it still doesn't work.
Do you have some solutions ?
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Facebook;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Dynamic;
using Windows;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;


namespace testfb
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private const string AppId = "APPID";
    private Uri _loginUrl;
    private const string _ExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me, publish_stream, offline_access";
    FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sid = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();

        Login();
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = AppId;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        parameters.response_type = "token";

        parameters.display = "popup";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ExtendedPermissions))
            parameters.scope = _ExtendedPermissions;

        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        _loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

        webBrowser2.Navigate(_loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: have you added the reference manually to the references node in your project..?

Comment: Yes I tried but I didn't find it.